# Visibility change on GitHub and Fork problem

Tags: github

I changed the [visibility](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility) of my project to the public and then returned it to Private this time the Forks became independent and how did I connect it to the parent repository?

What is the solution to this without a new fork?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the visibility of your project, it detaches all the forks.  That's because all the repositories in a repository network either are all public or are all private, and this is necessary because due to the way GitHub stores data, the objects in one repository are effectively visible through all the repositories.  If you were allowed to have one private repository in the same network as public repositories, then people could still get data from the private repository if they could guess or find out the object IDs.

If you need to reattach a fork to its former parent, return it to the proper visibility, and ask GitHub Support to do that.